# CreateJS and TypeScript 1.4

Tags: typescript, createjs, typescript1.4

I started my project with CreateJS in TypeScript 1.3 about 4 months ago. The problem came after TypeScript 1.4 release in January. I had to of course download new DefinitlyTyped libraries (from NuGet). My project has been broken - which I would accept if not a fact, that it does not work even in new projects. `*.d.ts` files unable to compile a project. It happens in `ECMAScript 5` and `ECMAScript 6` versions.

I have found that SoundJS definition contains the most error that unable loading a project and I got rid of it. But even so, I receive following errors:

```
 GameData.mapStage.canvas.width

Error   1   Property 'width' does not exist on type 'Object | HTMLCanvasElement'.
```

And I have to write something like that to use that property:

```
(<HTMLCanvasElement>(GameData.mapStage.canvas)).width
```

Resharper sees `<HTMLCanvasElement>` as redundant, because `canvas` is always `HTMLCanvasElement` witch is true, but TypeScript needs that casting.

The solution is also `easeljs.d.ts` modification, from:

```
canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | Object;
```

to

```
canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
```

The only way now to work with TypeScript 1.4 and CreateJS is not downloading `createjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped` package, and downloading separately `easeljs`, `tweenjs` and `preloadjs` type definitions packages. **No `SoundsJS` support...**

I have been waiting 2 months hoping, that new TypeDefinitions would come, but that not happened. Does CreateJS not support new TypeScript releases anymore?

Comment: Maybe @gskinner knows something about that issue?

Answer (score -1):

> The solution is also easeljs.d.ts modification, from: canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | Object;

This is a clear indication that your tooling (specifically resharper) doesn't support the *latest version of TypeScript i.e. 1.4*. Solution is to disable Resharper for TypeScript or use a beta version of Resharper.

Said another way: the DefinitelyTyped definitions are more up to date than your tooling i.e.

> Does CreateJS not support new TypeScript releases anymore?

That is exactly what they support. The latest versions.

Comment: So why sound.js DefinitelyTyped definitions break an application?

Comment: Disabling ReSharper does not help in cases described above. DefinitelyTyped definitions for CreateJS are written wrong.